# How do I set the line colour in an MSChart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I was wondering if someone could please show me sample code for setting the line colour in an MSChart using C#.

I know I can select a scheme form the options but I was wanting to pick my own colours for the different serie's I have shown.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 5):

```
Chart1.Series["MySeries"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(113, 152, 203);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are more used to hex colors:

```
chart1.Series["MySeries"].Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#001122");
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies to charts from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart`:

```
Chart1.SeriesCollection(1).Border.Color = Color.Orange;
```